# How to merge multiple arrays outside of their loops?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array from 2 other arrays. I am having a problem getting them merged outside of their loops.

Here is the code to build the 2 arrays:

```
$redDogs = '3';
$blueDogs = '2';

$i = 1;
// build red dogs array
$redDogs = (int)$redDogs;
while($i <= $redDogs) {
    $reds[] = 'red_dog_' . $i++;
}

    foreach ($reds as $red) {
        print '<pre>'; print_r($red); print '</pre>';
    }

$j = 1;
// build blue dogs array
$blueDogs = (int)$blueDogs;
while($j <= $blueDogs) {
    $blues[] = 'blue_dog_' . $j++;
}

    foreach ($blues as $blue) {
        print '<pre>'; print_r($blue); print '</pre>';
    }
```

How could I create an array like:

```
print_r($alldogs);
```

To produce the following output:

```
Array {
    [0] => red_dog_1
    [1] => red_dog_2
    [2] => red_dog_3
    [3] => blue_dog_1
    [4] => blue_dog_2
}
```

I have tried array_merge($red, $blue) but don't seem to get any values.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$merged = $reds + $blues;`

Comment: `$comb = array_merge($reds, $blues); var_dump($comb);`

Comment: `array_merge` returns the new merged array. So if you are just calling `array_merge($red, $blue)` by itself, it isn't going to do anything. And depending on what you want to do, a union (`+`) might work as well. The difference being that a union won't overwrite existing keys and merge will. Also merge will append numeric keys, re-indexing, while union will skip where they are the same.

Comment: cargo-cult programming: `$blueDogs = '2'; $blueDogs = (int)$blueDogs`. If you wanted integers, why didn't you just DEFINE them as integers in the first place? `$blueDogs = 2`

Comment: @MarcB - It is not in my control. It is returned from a variable that I do not have control of ...

Comment: @CharlotteDunois - as my question states this produces nothing ...

Comment: Really? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/daae4cad82d5a84723ac9439fc30b5a6c26aa7fd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$redDogs = '3';
$blueDogs = '2';

$i = 1;
// build red dogs array
$redDogs = (int)$redDogs;
while($i <= $redDogs) {
    $reds[] = 'red_dog_' . $i++;
}

$j = 1;
// build blue dogs array
$blueDogs = (int)$blueDogs;
while($j <= $blueDogs) {
    $blues[] = 'blue_dog_' . $j++;
}

print_r(array_merge($reds, $blues));
```

Merge your array before looping through the array.

Your foreach statements were converting your array to strings.

Comment: It's always better to include explanations why your example code answers the question than just posting some code.